# Wireless laser mouse is trailing behind

Tags: mouse

I have Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 8000. Time to time the cursor starts to trail / lag behind the actual motion. I cant quite get it - whether this is laser issue or Bluetooth issue.

Anyone knows what can I try to fix it?

Comment: This is why I don't like using wireless mice.  Step 1: try replacing the batteries in the mouse.  It may be a poor signal causing the movements to arrive late.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your DeskTop
Choose Personalize -> Change Mouse Pointers -> Pointer Options Tab -> Uncheck Display Pointer Trails -> click ok.

I don't understand what do you mean from time to time but I think this should fix the issue.

Comment: He doesn't mean a visual trail, he means the cursor is lagging behind the movement of the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

When my mouse wireless start to lag, there's two possibilities:

- Batteries low
- Inteference

Batteries low, is a easy solvable problem.

The interference it's bit harder, check if there's anything new between the receiver and the mouse, and check for any Bluetooth interference ( maybe even your cellphone).

I'll find it strange if it was the laser